# Contact Form 7 Will Not Email Me Submissions

Tags: forms, wordpress, contact-form-7

So I'm trying make my contact 7 form functional but for some reason i am not receiving the email even though the contact form successfully accepts submissions. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

here is the code for the form.

```
<section class="form-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="eight col center">
            <div class="text-center">
            <h3 class="h2">Get in touch with us, any time of the day!</h3>
            <p>We're always on the hunt for new, creative projects. If you want to talk about the ideas for your business, or if you just want to visit us and say hello, don't hesitate to send us a message via the form below.</p>
</div>
<div  class="form c-form">
<fieldset>
[text* your-name placeholder "Your Name"]
[email* your-email placeholder "Email"]
[text* text-909 4/ placeholder "3 + 1 ="]
[textarea your-message placeholder "Type your message here"]<div class="text-center">
[submit class:submit class:btn class:color value "Send Message"]
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

here is the email template I've set up:

From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
Subject: [your-subject]

Message Body:
[your-message]

--
This e-mail was sent from a contact form on Wavey Media Group (http://www.waveymediagroup.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may have to set your SMTP port and host in theme's header.php or in wp-config.php file